# Multi thread using Arc without a lock

Tags: rust

is it possible to use Arc without a lock? Because I really don't care the order of reading data. Here is my [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e8f64a37c55b710d891f0e103fb80b04).

```
use std::{sync::Arc, thread};

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let x = Arc::new(0);
    let y = Arc::clone(&x);
    thread::spawn(move || {
        for i in 0..10 {
            println!("exe:{},{}", i, y);
        }
    });
    while *x < 100000 {
        // Is it ok to change the value of x here?
        *x += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Even if you don't care about anything at all, Rust still does not allow data races. And if you only don't care about the order, you can still get unexpected results because the operation isn't atomic at CPU-level or because of compiler optimizations.

However, you don't have to use mutexes or other similar locks. You can use [atomics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/atomic/). And if you don't care about order you can use [`Ordering::Relaxed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/atomic/enum.Ordering.html#variant.Relaxed) that is going to be almost free (free on loads on x86 and I think ARM too, adds will have some overhead but it is marginal probably):

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicI32, Ordering};

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let x = Arc::new(AtomicI32::new(0));
    let y = Arc::clone(&x);
    thread::spawn(move || {
        for i in 0..10 {
            println!("exe:{},{}", i, y.load(Ordering::Relaxed));
        }
    });
    while x.load(Ordering::Relaxed) < 100000 {
        x.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }
}
```

Comment: For what that's worth, since only one location is involved I don't think stronger orderings would have any effect anyway: AFAIK their purpose is defining happens-before / happens-after relationships for load/store operations *to other locations*.

Comment: @Masklinn I must admit I'm not proficient with this subject, but I think the loop loading the atomic twice may have an effect.

Comment: I can't say I'm proficient either, but short of HTM I don't think atomics would do anything there, all they'd ensure is that the operations between the load and the store (add) would be visible if the store is. To make sure the load and store are related (e.g. if your counter was multithreaded and you didn't want to end up with x > 100000)  I believe you'd have to use a CAS. That's basically what `fetch_update` (which more or less implements this operation) does.

Answer (score 3):

`Arc` protects the reference count itself, it doesn't protect the data it references. Per [the `Arc` docs on Thread Safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#thread-safety):

> `Arc<T>` makes it thread safe to have multiple ownership of the same data, but it doesn’t add thread safety to its data.

The general docs for `Arc` note:

> Shared references in Rust disallow mutation by default, and `Arc` is no exception: you cannot generally obtain a mutable reference to something inside an `Arc`. If you need to mutate through an `Arc`, use `Mutex`, `RwLock`, or one of the `Atomic` types.

In short, `Arc` is not the appropriate type for what you're doing *by itself*. You could make it work just fine with an `Arc<AtomicI32>` or the like though, where the `Arc` maintains the lifetime, and the `AtomicI32` protects access to the data itself.